# How can i display all content under content type drupal

Tags: php, view, drupal-8

I have a create 2 Content type like

```
Finance Form 
HR_content_Form
```

Then NOw including article and page i have 4 content type

```
Article 
Basic Page
Finance Form 
HR_content_Form
```

Then i have added content under Finance Form and HR_content_Form.Now i want to  display all content under content type so i tried

```
$types = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
  ->getStorage('node_type')
  ->loadMultiple();





foreach ($types as $machine_name => $content_type) {
    $label[] = $content_type->label();

  }



echo '<pre>';print_r($label);
```

Now it display all content type. How can i display **datas i have added** under Finance Form ,HR_content_Form .Please help me

Answer (score 0):

You can [`loadByProperties`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityStorageBase.php/function/EntityStorageBase%3A%3AloadByProperties/8.2.x).

```
$types = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
  ->getStorage('node_type')
  ->loadByProperties(['type' => ['finance_form', 'hr_content_form']]);
```

Comment: thanks for your reply..I have added some data under this content type can i get that data?i want to display it

Comment: here 'finance_form', 'hr_content_form' are dynamic fields so how can i add names?

Comment: @shythyamenon Not sure I follow... now `$types` contains all nodes of those types. What do you mean with 'dynamic fields'? That you might want to load other types ? Then pass them as a variable. That they contain different fields? Then you need to refer to the `EntityTypeDefinition` to know what those are.

Comment: i have added datats under this content type.I want to get all added data.is there any way?

Comment: @shythyamenon Yes, you'd have to iterate your results and call the `::view()` method in your entities. But I think you'd be better served using Views directly.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT node_field_data.langcode AS node_field_data_langcode, node_field_data.created AS node_field_data_created, node_field_data.nid AS nid
FROM
{node_field_data} node_field_data
WHERE (node_field_data.status = '1') AND (node_field_data.type IN ('finance_form', 'hr_content_form'))
ORDER BY node_field_data_created DESC
LIMIT 11 OFFSET 0
```

Comment: thanks for the reply.how can i execute this  code in drupal?

Comment: Create view And  add Field then  ..  Filter Criteria --> Content Type --> Check  Content Type Name